# Slony cluster successfully created and sync'd, but no further replication

Tags: slony

Deb. Squeeze, Postgres 8.4, Slony 1.2.21

I've created a master > slave cluster which has done the initial copy. However, I can't get any more data to replicate. I've always been a bit baffled by what commands should be run to start the required processes/daemons at each end.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got the little bugger sorted. Potential Slony users note that (currently) Slony doesn't replicate Truncate statements, use delete from  instead.

This meant my original data was still in the slave and the PK clashed with the new data ,so it wasn't updated.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but with insert statements.... any ideas?